# Возможно ли сделать скриншот экрана используя php?

Tags: php, screenshots

PHP обновился но появился вопрос - получится ли сделать скриншот экрана сайта на PHP ?
`magegrabscreen();` не доступная функция в *nix, хотелось бы увидеть кроссплатформенное решение

Comment: так то лучше - а то минусов на ставят - тут это любят

Comment: экрана какого компьютера?

Comment: это не на компе , а к примеру на nnn.com сайт что бы  была функция сделать скин , на php.net есть такая функция но она не доступна *NIX и потому ищу другой вариант - кроссплатформенный

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, скриншот с помощью PHP сделать можно.

Нет, не подумайте, я прекрасно понимаю, что такое PHP и я "не в танке")

Для начала автору и тем, кто придет сюда в поисках ответа на вопрос "как в PHP сделать скриншот экрана" (ответ господина @Ипатьев показался мне недостаточно доходчивым): PHP исполняется на сервере, а не на клиенте (не в браузере). Он за многие километры от клиента, где-то в дата-центре (как правило), и не имеет никакого доступа к экрану пользователя. Поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос, каким он кажется на первый взгляд: конечно нет, скриншот в PHP сделать нельзя. Скриншоты делаются в браузере.

Но, не отменяя последнего утверждения, на сервере можно поднять браузерный движок, который отрендерит страницу и тогда из нее можно сделать изображение. Но вы должны понимать, что это **не скриншот сайта у пользователя**. Это ваш сервер открыл страницу вашего сайта и сделал с нее скриншот. И с пользователем это действие никак не связано.

**Конкретика**

Однажды у меня была подобная задача и я вполне успешно использовал phantomjs. Это утилита с версиями под windows или linux, которая включает в себя webkit-движок (о да! никаких проблем с версткой!).

Порядок действий примерно такой (делал это пару лет назад и, конечно, не помню точно):

**1** - Установить phantomjs. Страница download: http://phantomjs.org/download.html
Я использовал под debian и опытом под виндой поделиться не могу.

**2** - Использовать сие чудо можно через либы под PHP или без них, как вам удобно. Я пользовался просто вызывая системную команду такого вида (могла измениться за эти годы):

```
"$phantom $rasterize 'http$domen/template.php?tgb=$tgb&title=$title&text=$text&image=$image&dalign=$dalign' $out $width $height"
//$phantom - путь к исполняемому файлу phantomjs
//$rasterize - путь к rasterize (если не ошибаюсь, это часть phantomjs, которая отвечает за "превращение" отрендеренной страницы в изображение - растеризацию. У меня она лежала в директории с фантомом: phantomjs/examples/rasterize.js)
//дальше адрес страницы
//$out - выходное изображение
//$width & $height - размеры выходного изображения
```

Но если бы я собирался использовать phantomjs сегодня - я бы подключил либу. К примеру, сразу в гугле - https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs

Comment: вот этот ответ меня устраивает , но меня смутило что только библиотека из видоса только Под windows

Comment: @Geyan в смысле, сам phantom? да, для каждой платформы своя версия. а какие с этим проблемы?

Comment: проблемы в том что я не знаю как это делать , и ещё проблема нарисовалась на данный момент , нанесение водяного знака на видео , в линуксе проблемы с подобным софтом , видеоредакторы есть и даже векторный редактор - но водяной знак получается на 1:4 экрана

Comment: @Geyan не понял, не знаете как делать что? Как установить прогу под виндой/линуксом? Под виндой, вроде бы, ничего сложного. Под линуксом - загуглите "install phantom linux" и будет счастье)

Comment: не на комп же а на сервер , скринить же не на компе будут а на сервере , я всегда линуксом пользуюсь , у меня Gnom 3

Comment: а серв - не комп?) чем там установка отличается от установки на вашем компе?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43680/discussion-between-geyan-and--).

Comment: Подозреваю, что сервер - виртуальный хостинг. Тогда никак.

Answer (score 7):

Это хороший вопрос. На понимание того, что такое РНР.

Аббревиатура PHP означает PHP HTML Preprocessor. То есть, РНР занимается предварительной подготовкой HTML, и для этой задачи он подходит великолепно. Для не связанных же с этим задач, если в РНР и есть решение, то оно обычно рудиментарное и малопригодное, занесенное в язык случайно.

Поэтому ответ на вопрос "Возможно ли сделать скриншот экрана на php?" будет точно такой же, как на вопросы "Можно ли писать музыку с помощью РНР?", "Можно ли варить кофе с помощью РНР", "Можно ли управлять космическим марсоходом с помощью РНР?":

Можно. Надо только найти программу, которая делает то что нам нужно, и вызвать ее с помощью команды system().

Comment: какую программу ? в ехе ? или я не понял но есть код и могу дополнить , и есть очень жирное **НО** это не кроссплатформенно

Comment: Если длинного ответа недостаточно, то вот тебе короткий - на РНР сделать скриншот экрана сайта нельзя.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=np93Aox6ijs  поглянь видео , можно же и без подключения всяких сайтов

Comment: Расширение СОМ доступно только под виндоус. Чем быстрее ты поймешь, что РНР не предназначен для делания снимков экрана и что коссплатформенного решения не существует, тем быстрее сдвинешься с мертвой точки

Comment: а другими способами можно ?

Comment: Справедливости ради, PHP давно уже перерос язык только для препроцессинга HTML.

Comment: А разве не Personal Home Page? )

Comment: Nick  это точно нет - Hypertext Preprocessor  вот так точнее

Comment: "то оно обычно рудиментарное и малопригодное, занесенное в язык случайно." какой кхе. любой язык програмирования может использоватся в любых целей. люди пишут на пхп андроид проги, десктоп проги. А на джаве люди пишут сайты(пример одноклассники). Я не призываю писать пхп проги на андроид, я вообще против си и любого иного языка кроме джавы на андроиде.

Answer (score 3):

Можешь сам написать, ничего готового не знаю.
Для винды есть функция в доке, в линуксе скрин можно сделать
используя:

- gnome-screenshot если гном,
- ksnapshot если kde
- или используя import если установлен imagemagick:

  ```
  import -window root -delay 200 screenshot.png
  ```

Comment: да уж , это не ответ - лучше удали и в комментарии к вопросу оформи

Comment: А мне нравится, больше конкретики чем у Ипатьева. Ну и если вызывать командой `system()`, то ваши решения вроде как подходят. Предлагаю восстановить.

Comment: Хороший совет. Import вещь. перешел на него со scroot.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы раз и на всегда избавиться от всех нюансов с микро вопросами:

Да, с помощью php можно сделать на платформе Windows скриншот экрана или часть его.
Но...
Сам процесс получения скриншота ( не важно чем "COM, imagegrabscreen, FFI" ), **обработав** его в читаемую API данных "GD", очень ресурсно-затратный.

Тут и вступают как сказать "внешнее выполнение", через консоль, шелл, чтобы получить быстрый "опять же" GD ресурс API.

На сегодняшний момент, самый эффективный способ получения скриншота - это через **nircmdc**

А теперь немного кода и теста:

php 7.4

```
<?php

$s = microtime ( true );

imagegrabscreen ();

$e = microtime ( true );

var_dump ( $e - $s );


#############

$s = microtime ( true );

exec ( 'nircmdc.exe savescreenshot screen.png' );

ImageCreateFromPNG ( 'screen.png' );

$e = microtime ( true );

var_dump ( $e - $s );
```

Быстродействие:

```
float(1.2110691070557) // imagegrabscreen
float(0.11100697517395) // nircmdc + ImageCreateFromPNG
```

https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/savescreenshot.html

И на десерт! Чтобы еще консоль мелочи не ждать "с завершением чего то там..".
Просто посылаем запрос и закрываем поток.

```
pclose ( popen ( 'nircmdc.exe savescreenshot screen.png', 'r' ) );
```

---

Чтобы использовать скриншот напрямую, без троллинга HDD/иного устройства с сохранением тела:

```
$command = <<<'command'
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.Drawing" ) > $null
$Bitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap 100, 100
$Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 100, 100
$FromImage = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage( $Bitmap )
$FromImage.CopyFromScreen( 100, 100, 0, 0, $size, [System.Drawing.CopyPixelOperation]::SourceCopy )
$FromImage.Dispose()
$MemoryStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$Bitmap.save( $MemoryStream, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::png )
$Bytes = $MemoryStream.ToArray()
$Bitmap.Dispose()
$MemoryStream.Flush()
$MemoryStream.Dispose()
return [convert]::ToBase64String( $Bytes )
command;

$s = microtime (1);
var_dump ( shell_exec ( 
    $a = 'powershell -sta "' . strtr ( $command, [
        '"' => '\"',
        PHP_EOL => '; '
    ] ) . '"'
) );
$e = microtime (1);

echo $e - $s;
```

Time:

```
0.29001712799072
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй библиотеку html2canvas. (Screenshots with JavaScript)

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/