# Получить или сделать ScreenShot любого сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-служба

Здравствуйте.

Как можно получить скрин сайта, есть какое то API?
Я покопался в интернете везде для этого деньги просят.
Можно как-то самому сделать такую функцию и как?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614246/making-a-screenshot-of-the-current-website-using-html-or-javascript

Comment: Странно, как же вы искали если по запросу *site screenshot* выдает полно бесплатных сервисов. Более того можно в любом браузере найти расширений кучу

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы меня не так поняли, у меня сайт в котором очень много ссылок, и мне нужно добавить кнопку на эти ссылки, чтобы пользователи могли не переходя по ссылке посмотреть скриншот сайта.

Comment: @Alexander Там создаётся скрин данного сайта, который открыт в браузере, мне нужно получить это без открытии сайта.

Comment: А почему нельзя заранее сделать скриншоты и залить на сайт и чтоб пользователь смотрел уже эти картинки? Если бы у вас сайт ориентировался бы на показе скриншотов сайтов любой страницы, я бы еще понял. Но если всего лишь показывается один скрин на одну ссылку - проще себе их закачать и не мучиться

Comment: @АлексейШиманский У меня сайт который помогает сохранять ссылки, в "папки", пользователь сам должен добавлять ссылки, всё в его контроле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы, на вашем месте, использовал [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) или его аналоги. Простой пример:

```
phantomjs test.js http://zub96.ru test.png
```

В файл test.js добавим код:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address, output, size;

if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
    console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL filename [paperwidth*paperheight|paperformat] [zoom]');
    console.log('  paper (pdf output) examples: "5in*7.5in", "10cm*20cm", "A4", "Letter"');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 600 };
    if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[2].substr(-4) === ".png") {
        size = system.args[3].split('*');
        page.paperSize = size.length === 2 ? { width: size[0], height: size[1], margin: '0px' }
                                           : { format: system.args[3], orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' };
    }
    if (system.args.length > 4) {
        page.zoomFactor = system.args[4];
    }
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit();
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.render(output);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 200);
        }
    });
}
```

На выходе получим png файл test.png[image: Изображение создано phantojs] , а дальше уже его обработать можно, как Вам нужно.

Comment: Как раз это и смотрел, спасибо большое за пример, я сообщу если что нибудь получиться.

Comment: Можно это всё сделать автоматически?

Comment: Можно. Добавить, в скрипт добавления сайта в папку, вызов phantomjs или использовать готовые библиотеки, например [PHP PhantomJS](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/) , для других языков тоже есть.

Comment: А есть какая то инструкция для новичков, там не всё так понятно

Comment: А у Вас с чем именно трудности? С фантомом, интеграцией или какой-то библиотекой? У Вас сервис как организован?

Answer (score 0):

В firefox, в инспекторе, есть кнопка сделать скриншот. Возможно, нужно написать расширение для браузера и вызывать программно эту функцию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это можно сделать только с mozila firefox ведь так?

Comment: да только с mozila firefox. ещё кажется в хроме тоже появилась эта функция, но я не уверен на 100% не могу найти у себя.

Comment: Но ведь для этого нужно открыть же сайт, а мне нужно получить скрин без его открытии

Comment: можно с помощью php http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553351/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-php?rq=1